# Keeping rotation values within a range of 0 to 360°

Tags: drivers

How can I keep the rotation values within a range of 0 to 360° no matter how many times I actually rotated an object? I need this as a value for a driver variable.

For example 945° => 225°.

Comment: Thanks again, `var - var // (2 * pi) * 2 * pi` and `var % (2 * pi` both deliver a positive result, which is the positional equivalent to its negative. E.g. -980° => 100° (= -260°). Is there a way to get the precise negative result for negative values directly? I want to keep the sign (+/-) as directional information.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you probably want `fmod`

Answer (score 3):

**Modulo's partner in crime.**

Alternatively to modulus could use its partner in crime div. `a // (2 * pi)` is how many integer multiples of 2pi the value is, eg if `a = -3 * pi / 2` we get -1. If we subtract -1 multiples of 2pi  from `a` we get `pi / 2`.

```
a - a // (2 * pi) * 2 * pi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo `x % 360.0`, or `x % (2 * pi)` when operating in radians, which will wrap around to zero when the value x reaches a multiple of 360.0 or 2.

If you want signed results you can use `fmod(x, 2*pi)`.

Beware of floating point inaccuracies when using the `%` operator.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it as a scripted expression `var%(2*pi) if var > 0 else var%(2*-pi)`  (var = rotation value in radians), which does what I want both for positive and negative rotation values. But the negative ones are not precisely calculated, so I get for -360° not 0° but -0.00001°? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Equivalent of `fabs(var % (2 * pi))`

Comment: In hindsight the `fabs` is unnecessary For some reason `abs` isn't in the driver namespace.  .  @Jacquin  When using modulo the result   `a % b`  is always sign of `b`. This  explains the sign. Hence simply use  `var % (2 * pi)` Please accept this answer.